# CMake not generating compile_commands.json

Tags: c++, json, cmake, clang

I'm new to CMake and I'm trying to create the compile_commands.json file to use with clang, but I'm having some difficulties generating the file and I'm not sure why. I've been able to use cmake to compile the binary `person` that I have below, but after that was successful I've been unable to get it to output the compile commands.

I've also tried doing the -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS=ON flag, but that didn't work either. So far there's been no errors, but also no output.

Here's what my CMakeLists.txt file looks like:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.6)
project (Tutorial)
set(CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS ON)
add_executable(person Person.cc Pirate.cc main.cc)
```

Comment: Which generator and version of CMake are you using? I've had trouble generating the compile_commands.json file using the XCode generator, but for Ninja and Makefiles it works ok.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This ended up being an issue with using an old version of CMake. I ended up installing the newest version and it worked as expected.

According to Clang docs

*"Currently CMake (since 2.8.5) supports generation of compilation databases for Unix Makefile builds (Ninja builds in the works) with the option CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS."*

Comment: What versions did it fail on, and what did you upgrade to?

Comment: Haven't checked this thoroughly, but 2.6 definitely did not work, but anything >= 3.0 has seemed to work fine, so the feature was added somewhere in that range.

Comment: Just found the exact answer here: 
http://clang.llvm.org/docs/JSONCompilationDatabase.html
"Currently CMake (since 2.8.5) supports generation of compilation databases for Unix Makefile builds (Ninja builds in the works) with the option CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS."

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that.

Answer (score 11):

I had the same problem, `compile_commands.json` was not generated with cmake, version 3.16.0.
It was generated when I used the `Ninja` generator, but not `Unix Makefiles`.

That [discussion](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/16588) gave me the fix:

```
set(CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS ON) # does not produce the json file
set(CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS ON CACHE INTERNAL "") # works
```

Comment: You should use $ENV{} syntax to check/access environment variables such as CMAKE_* within `CMakeLists.txt`. https://stackoverflow.com/a/68724763/717355

Comment: It's also a normal var: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS.html

Answer (score 10):

I also encountered the same problem as you.
According to [CMake doc](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS.html)

> This option (CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS) is implemented only by Makefile Generators and the Ninja. It is ignored on other generators.

Thus, there is no solution to generate *compile_commands.json* file when using MSVC.